# What is calling method and called method?

Tags: java, function, methods

Are calling method and called method both same?

What I would like to know is "calling method" means the method which calls another method that is main method in most cases, or the main method itself?

Comment: The caller makes a call and is calling the callee who is being called. ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The calling method is the method that contains the actual call; the called method is the method being called. They are different. For example:

```
// Calling method
void f()
{
    g();
}

// Called method
void g()
{
}
```

Comment: Regarding this terminology @StuartGolodetz, If the 'g' method also made a call to another method (say h();) would it be considered both a caller *and* a worker method?  Also, what if the 'g' method just made use of a standard Java API method like, for example println("something"); again, would 'g' be considered both a caller *and* a worker in that situation? I know technically, in both cases it would be both a caller *and* a worker method, but I'm asking if there are any special situations in which these terms are not applied.

Comment: @Zippy: A function is the caller or callee *with respect to a particular call*. If `g` calls `h`, then it is the caller with respect to that call to `h` (and `h` is the callee with respect to that call). The `g` function could still independently be the callee of another call (e.g. the one made in `f` in this example). It's not common to talk about a function as being a caller in general (i.e. out of the context of a particular call) - in other words, to say that `f` is a "caller" because there exists at least one call to another function within `f`.

Answer (score 6):

The calling method is the method that contains the actual call.

The called method is the method being called. They are different.

They are also called the Caller and the Callee methods.

For example

```
int caller(){
int x=callee();
}

int callee(){
return 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

called method means initialization of a method.
calling method means where we are using that initialized method.

Comment: This is not correct. In fact a method can be both called and the caller when it's calling itself. What you're talking about is the definition.